# Printing base64 PDF using PDF.JS on document load

Tags: javascript, pdf, printing, pdf.js

I am trying to print a pdf with PDF.js but currently I cannot get the document data rendered in the pdf element. This is what it looks like right now:
[image: eg]
So, no data is being rendered.

This is the code behind:

```
<script  src="jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="pdf.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="pdf.worker.js"></script>

<body id="printbody" style="margin:0px;">
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">    
        var pdfData = atob('JVBERi0xLjQK...'); //Shortened
        PDFJS.workerSrc = 'pdf.worker.js';        
        PDFJS.getDocument({data: pdfData}).then(function RenderAndPrint(res) {
            var src = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([res], { type: 'application/pdf' }))
            var printFrame = document.createElement('iframe');
            printFrame.id = 'print-frame';
            //printFrame.style.display = 'none';
            printFrame.style.width = '100%'
            printFrame.style.height = '100%'
            printFrame.style.border = 'none'
            printFrame.src = src;
            document.body.appendChild(printFrame);
            setTimeout(function () {
            printFrame.contentWindow.print();
            }, 0)       
        });    
</script>
```

The final goal is to have this entire page appended to an existing page via AJAX so the as soon as the this page is appended and renders the PDF, the iframe (which would be hidden) would print the pdf as soon as it renders and then eventually dispose of itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using itextsharp, I instead saved the pdf to the local system, set it to print on open like so:

```
PdfAction print = new PdfAction(PdfAction.PRINTDIALOG);
writer.SetOpenAction(print);
```

and then used an iframe to render the pdf by setting the file to the src